# admob same AdRequest for both banners and interstitials or different AdRequest?

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

I had to implement banners and interstitials (I know:-), without compromising User Interaction!!!),

I am confusing about using **Same adRequest** for both banners and interstitials

```
AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);

InterstitialAd interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
interstitial.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.MY_AD_UNIT_ID));
interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
```

**(OR)**

use **different adRequest** for each

```
AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);

InterstitialAd interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
interstitial.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.MY_AD_UNIT_ID));
AdRequest adRequest2 = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
interstitial.loadAd(adRequest2);
```

Will there be any compromises related to "Sending multiple AdRequests" or any Lags in performance or still any issues?

Answer (score 2):

There are no issues with sending a banner request at the same time as an interstitial request.

I would tend to use 2 separate AdRequests for clarity.